# why is the lift web framework scalable?

Tags: web-services, scala, frameworks, lift

I want to know the technical reasons why the lift webframework has high performance and scalability?  I know it uses scala, which has an actor library, but according to the install instructions it default configuration is with jetty. So does it use the actor library to scale?

Now is the scalability built right out of the box.  Just add additional servers and nodes and it will automatically scale, is that how it works?  Can it handle 500000+ concurrent connections with supporting servers.

I am trying to create a web services framework for the enterprise level, that can beat what is out there and is easy to scale, configurable, and maintainable.  My definition of scaling is just adding more servers and you should be able to accommodate the extra load.

Thanks

Comment: This really is a huge subject, I think you better focus your answer to specific areas of server software

Answer (score 170):

Lift's approach to scalability is within a single machine. Scaling across machines is a larger, tougher topic.  The short answer there is: Scala and Lift don't do anything to either help or hinder horizontal scaling.

As far as actors within a single machine, Lift achieves better scalability because a single instance can handle more concurrent requests than most other servers. To explain, I first have to point out the flaws in the classic thread-per-request handling model.  Bear with me, this is going to require some explanation.

A typical framework uses a thread to service a page request. When the client connects, the framework assigns a thread out of a pool. That thread then does three things: it reads the request from a socket; it does some computation (potentially involving I/O to the database); and it sends a response out on the socket.  At pretty much every step, the thread will end up blocking for some time.  When reading the request, it can block while waiting for the network. When doing the computation, it can block on disk or network I/O. It can also block while waiting for the database.  Finally, while sending the response, it can block if the client receives data slowly and TCP windows get filled up. Overall, the thread might spend 30 - 90% of it's time blocked.  It spends 100% of its time, however, on that one request.

A JVM can only support so many threads before it really slows down. Thread scheduling, contention for shared-memory entities (like connection pools and monitors), and native OS limits all impose restrictions on how many threads a JVM can create.

Well, if the JVM is limited in its maximum number of threads, and the number of threads determines how many concurrent requests a server can handle, then the number of concurrent requests will be determined by the number of threads.

(There are other issues that can impose lower limits---GC thrashing, for example. Threads are a fundamental limiting factor, but not the only one!)

Lift decouples thread from requests. In Lift, a request does *not* tie up a thread. Rather, a thread does an action (like reading the request), then sends a message to an actor. Actors are an important part of the story, because they are scheduled via "lightweight" threads.  A pool of threads gets used to process messages within actors. It's important to avoid blocking operations inside of actors, so these threads get returned to the pool rapidly.  (Note that this pool isn't visible to the application, it's part of Scala's support for actors.)  A request that's currently blocked on database or disk I/O, for example, doesn't keep a request-handling thread occupied. The request handling thread is available, almost immediately, to receive more connections.

This method for decoupling requests from threads allows a Lift server to have many more concurrent requests than a thread-per-request server.  (I'd also like to point out that the Grizzly library supports a similar approach without actors.)  More concurrent requests means that a single Lift server can support more users than a regular Java EE server.

Comment: I think you are victim of a hit and run questioner. Your answer is far better then the question itself deserves.

Comment: @mtnygard: you say "it's important to avoid blocking operations inside of actors". What if I need to do some I/O that could potentially block for some time? Should I launch another thread?

Comment: this is not something special with lift. This is basically what NIO does with selectors. And most modern java based servers are made this way

Comment: N.B. I don't think the above explanation is correct; see http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/e62a2754528c9f2f/f85ef36bde2ea71c#f85ef36bde2ea71c

Comment: >`decoupling requests from threads ... Lift server ... more concurrent requests than a thread-per-request server ...  Lift server can support more users than a regular Java EE server.` - What about Servlet 3.0's async support? See e.g. http://javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html

Answer (score 20):

at mtnyguard

"Scala and Lift don't do anything to either help or hinder horizontal scaling"

Ain't quite right. Lift is highly statefull framework. For example if a user requests a form, then he can only post the request to the same machine where the form came from, because the form processeing action is saved in the server state.

And this is actualy a thing which hinders scalability in a way, because this behaviour is inconistent to the shared nothing architecture.

No doubt that lift is highly performant but perfomance and scalability are two different things. So if you want to scale horizontaly with lift you have to define sticky sessions on the loadbalancer which will redirect a user during a session to the same machine.

Comment: Yep... that's right and Foursquare and Novell Pulse both demonstrate that Lift's sticky session requirement has not been an issue for horizontal scaling... and with the upcoming commercial Lift Cluster Manager, management of the cluster will be even easier.

Comment: Where is Lift Cluster Manager ?

Answer (score 3):

Jetty maybe the point of entry, but the actor ends up servicing the request, I suggest having a look at the twitter-esque example, 'skitter' to see how you would be able to create a very scalable service. IIRC, this is one of the things that made the twitter people take notice.

Answer (score 1):

I really like @dre's reply as he correctly states the statefulness of lift being a potential problem for horizontal scalability.

The problem - 
Instead of me describing the whole thing again, check out the discussion (Not the content) on this post. http://javasmith.blogspot.com/2010/02/automagically-cluster-web-sessions-in.html

Solution would be as @dre said sticky session configuration on load balancer on the front and adding more instances. But since request handling in lift is done in thread + actor combination you can expect one instance handle more requests than normal frameworks. This would give an edge over having sticky sessions in other frameworks. i.e. Individual instance's capacity to process more may help you to scale

- you have Akka lift integration which would be another advantage in this.